# multiple run and automatic response for each run in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch file to run a software several times. Each time the software is executed, a window with two choices will appear, and the default is just clicking enter. I don't want to click enter for each run, so I would like to write an automatic answer in my batch file.  Is it possible?

Comment: probably depends on the software. you might be able to put a command line flag when calling the program in your batch file to answer it, but that depends on if the software checks that.

Comment: Can you put down the code you have so far?

Comment: It would be good if you post what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer to your question is no.

However, with the help of the software you are launching, or an external tool, you might be able to achieve this.

If this other software accepts parameters, then maybe it provides one to automatically answer that first dialog that pops up.

Otherwise, you can use tools such as [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to simulate a user click in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Piping a carriage return works for some programs - that technique depends on the tool.

So see if this works for your program.

```
echo.|"c:\folder\filename.exe"
```